# inittab not restarting service after service crash in Red Hat 6.7

Tags: linux, redhat, init, restart, inittab

NOTE: I am running Red Hat 6.7

I have a service that is configured with the Linux init system to start a process as a service when the machine boots. This was done by doing this one-time configuration from the command line:

```
ln -snf /home/me/bin/my_service /etc/init.d/my_service
chkconfig --add my_service
chkconfig --level 235 my_service on
```

When the OS reboots, the service starts as expected.

I ALSO need the service to be restarted if the service (my_service) crashes. From what I've read, all I need to do is add an entry to /etc/inittab that looks like this:

mysvc:235:respawn:/home/me/bin/my_service_starter

Where my_service_starter looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/me/bin/my_service start
```

My understanding is that when the init system detects that my_service is not running, it will attempt to restart it by running "my_service_starter".

However this does not seem to be working.

I need to understand how to tell the Linux init system to restart my service when the service crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Given an entry like:

```
mysvc:235:respawn:/home/me/bin/my_service_starter
```

Then inittab will:

1. call `/home/me/bin/my_service_starter`
2. which will call `/home/me/bin/my_service start`
3. ...and then exit, so `init` will thing your service has failed
4. so `init` will call `/home/me/bin/my_service_starter` *again*

...and so forth, which will result in init deciding that your script is respawning too fast, after which it will ignore it completely.

A process started by inittab is *not expected to exit*.  If you really want to use inittab to maintain your service, you could *remove* `/etc/init.d/my_service`, and then in `/etc/inittab` you would have something like:

```
mysvc:235:respawn:/home/me/bin/my_service
```

And you would need to ensure that `my_service` runs in the foreground (some programs automatically daemonize by default, although these will often have some sort of `--run-in-foreground` flag).

If you upgrade to CentOS 7 or something else with systemd, this all becomes easier.

You can also investigate "third-party" process supervisors like "supervisord" or "runit" that you could use for process monitoring/restarting on CentOS 6.

*Update*

As mangotang points out, and I forgot, RHEL 6 actually shipped with upstart, even though it used almost exclusively SysV-style init scripts.  So a better solution would be to create an upstart service instead.  There are some reasonable getting-started docs [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/).

Comment: Part of what is unclear to me is:
does Red Hat 6.7 use the System V init (which uses inittab), or does it use Upstart? This info seems to suggest that Red Hat 6.7 uses Upstart:
http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/tip/RHEL-6-ditches-System-V-init-for-Upstart-What-Linux-admins-need-to-know

Does upstart also use the inittab file?

Comment: Actually, RHEL 6 uses *both*.  So you could actually write an upstart service to accomplish the same thing.  I always forget that upstart support was there, because it was largely unused and has since gone away in RHEL 7.

Comment: At the top of my RHEL 6's inittab file, it says:

`# inittab is only used by upstart for the default runlevel.
#
# ADDING OTHER CONFIGURATION HERE WILL HAVE NO EFFECT ON YOUR SYSTEM.`

I am wondering if this means that I can't expect the inittab stuff to work, and must use upstart?

Comment: Also: after making sure that my service's script runs in the foreground, and rebooting, my service does not start. Guessing that this must mean the inittab does not work the way I expected with RHEL 6.7. I'll have to give upstart a try.

Answer (score 1):

On RHEL 6.X, at top of the /etc/inittab file it says:

```
# inittab is only used by upstart for the default runlevel. 
# 
# ADDING OTHER CONFIGURATION HERE WILL HAVE NO EFFECT ON YOUR SYSTEM
```

RHEL 6.X uses Upstart instead of the System V init system. See the man pages for initctl(8) and initctl(5), or ask Google about Upstart.